# MediaPlayer crashes onStop()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I just made an example app for playing a sound. Playing works but if i press the button my app crashes. The code seems to be correct in my eyes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playAlarm();
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClick());
}

private void playAlarm() {
    Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class ButtonClick implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.stop(); //Getting a NullPointerException
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I don't have any idea how to fix this. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? Also, post a stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you do have playAlarm() happen before you click on the button. you need mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer() before mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert); (there's other errors here too, but that's the cause of the NPE). You should also remove e.printstackTrace() and just let it happen.